# Global or Local min of $f(x,y)=(x)^{2x}+(2y)^{y}$

Tags: real-analysis

I consider $f(x,y)=(x)^{2x}+(2y)^{y}$.This function is always positive in the domain and i found a min in $(1/e,1/(2e))$.Is it a global or local min?

Comment: I think this is a local minimum

Comment: Have you check the values of $f$ near the boundary of the domain and for large $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you tell if a maxima or minima is global or local](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484449/how-do-you-tell-if-a-maxima-or-minima-is-global-or-local)

Comment: @mavavilj: The question you reference concerns the problem of finding the global minimum of a univariate function whose domain is a closed, bounded interval. So although the questions may be related, this question is definitely not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: You are lucky to have two "non-interacting" variables $x,y$.

Comment: @quasi This would certainly be a duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2492055/max-and-min-of-fx-y-x2x2yy?rq=1 ?

Comment: @mavavilj: Yes, definitely a duplicate of _that_ one. Moreover. that question has the same OP as this one!

Comment: @GiulyB: Why are you asking the exact same question you asked over a year ago?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x,y)=(x)^{2x}+(2y)^{y}$, on the domain $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x,y > 0\}$.

For $x > 0$, let $g(x)=x^{2x}$, and for $y > 0$, let $h(y)=(2y)^y$.

Since $g'(x)=2\bigl(x^{2x}\bigr)(\ln(x)+1)$, it follows that

- $g$ is strictly decreasing on the interval $\bigl(0,{\large{\frac{1}{e}}}\large{]}$.

  $g$ is strictly increasing on the interval $\large{[}{\large{\frac{1}{e}}},\infty\bigr)$.

hence $g$ has a global minimum at $x={\large{\frac{1}{e}}}$.

Since $h'(y)=(2y)^y(\ln(2y)+1)$, it follows that

- $h$ is strictly decreasing on the interval $\bigl(0,{\large{\frac{1}{2e}}}\large{]}$.

  $h$ is strictly increasing on the interval $\large{[}{\large{\frac{1}{2e}}},\infty\bigr)$.

hence $h$ has a global minimum at $y={\large{\frac{1}{2e}}}$.

Thus, for all $x,y > 0$, we have
$$
f(x,y)=g(x)+h(y)\ge g\bigl({\small{\frac{1}{e}}}\bigr)+h\bigl({\small{\frac{1}{2e}}}\bigr)=f\bigl({\small{\frac{1}{e}}},{\small{\frac{1}{2e}}}\bigr)
$$
hence $f$ has a global minimum at $(x,y)=\bigl({\large{\frac{1}{e}}},{\large{\frac{1}{2e}}}\bigr)$.